# Firestore security rules: is it possible to chain get() and exists()

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Firestore Security Rules: Is there a way to "chain" a get and an exists ?
I would like to call exists() but I need to get() the docID first. Something like:
    exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/Collection2/  ** here I should do a get(/...) to obtain the desired docID ** );

I tried to make all in one line, 2 functions, ... I couldn't get anything to work.

```
function f1(entryParam) {
  return get(/..).data.myDocId;
}

function f2(docID) {
  returns exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/collection2/$(docID));
}
```

and then:

```
match /col3/{doc3ID} {
  allow xx: if f2(f1(doc3ID));
}
```

None of what I tried worked.
Do I really have to have the needed data "by hand", i.e., within one query distance?

Thanks in advance for your help / answers.
Philippe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (RTFM!)
the trick is to use the path object:
[rules.Path documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path)